# Thumbnailator conversion from PNG to JPG results in all-white image

Tags: png, jpeg, thumbnails

For many images, this code works fine to convert a PNG image to JPG:

```
Thumbnails.of(pngIn)
        .outputFormat("jpg")
        .scale(1.0)
        .toFile(jpgOut);
```

But for this specific image:
[image]

the code results in an all-white JPG image.  If someone can point me to the right way of doing things in Thumbnailator, I would very much appreciate it.  Cheers!

EDIT: Well, something in the image upload / download process makes things work for the attached image!  (The downloaded image is 50K while the original image is 41K, so clearly there's some funkiness going on there.) But I promise that the original PNG really does not work.

EDIT 2: [This link](https://www.google.com/search?q=pink%20cross%20stroke%20ink%20brush%20pen%20red%20ink%20brush%20pngwing.com&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjG0fevkobvAhUIA98KHUDqBBcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pink%20cross%20stroke%20ink%20brush%20pen%20red%20ink%20brush%20pngwing.com&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CwuAJY9coCYJvNAmgAcAB4AIABXIgBzgaSAQIxMpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=kCw4YMbJFoiG_AbA1JO4AQ&bih=701&biw=1404#imgrc=4157MPkLiS_pSM) to Google images can be used to download the 920x900 PNGWing image (41K) on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The above syntax seems to be correct for converting PNG to JPG.  The problem is that when the referenced image is read into a BufferedImage object, the image's type is BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY.  While such images can be 1, 2, or 4-bit images, Thumbnailator doesn't handle 2- or 4-bit images correctly, essentially assuming that the image is a 1-bit image.

In short: the syntax is correct, but there appears to be a Thumbnailator bug that hinders successful processing of some PNG files.